# ElasticSearch NEST client not returning results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am running a simple query through the ElasticSearch NEST C# client.  I receive results when I run the same query through http, but I get zero documents returned from the client.

This is how I populated the data set:

`curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/blog/posts" -d @blog.json`

This POST request returns a JSON result:

`http://localhost:9200/_search?q=adipiscing`

This is the code I have that is not returning anything.

```
public class Connector
{
    private readonly ConnectionSettings _settings;
    private readonly ElasticClient _client;

    public Connector()
    {
        _settings = new ConnectionSettings("localhost", 9200);
        _settings.SetDefaultIndex("blog");
        _client = new ElasticClient(_settings);
    }

    public IEnumerable<BlogEntry> Search(string q)
    {
        var result =
            _client.Search<BlogEntry>(s => s.QueryString(q));

        return result.Documents.ToList();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?  Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NEST tries to guess the type and index name and in your case it will use /blog/blogentries

`blog` because that what you told the default index is and `blogentries` because it will lowercase and pluralize the type name you pass to `Search<T>`.

You can control which type and index like so:

```
 .Search<BlogEntry>(s=>s.AllIndices().Query(...));
```

This will let NEST know you actually want to search on all indices and so nest will translate it to `/_search` on the root, equal to the command you issued on curl.

What you most likely want is:

```
 .Search<BlogEntry>(s=>s.Type("posts").Query(...));
```

So that NEST searches in `/blog/posts/_search`

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this because the name of my model didn't match the index name. Furthermore, the index name is not inferred if using the Object Initializer Syntax (I guess it defaults to all indexes). Would be nice to have a way to make it more obvious. (I'd say the "Explicit is better than implicit" principle would work here)

Comment: It should not default to all indices even if you use the object initializer syntax, mind opening a ticket on github with what your code looks like?