# Getting Empty Results using NEST for ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I ma making my first steps using ElasticSearch and NEST C# library for .NET. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Nest;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"));
        setting.SetDefaultIndex("Post");
        var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

        var post = new Post();
        post.id = 1;
        post.title = "the title";

        var t = client.Index(post);

        var results = client.Search<Post>(s => s.From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Fields(f => f.id, f => f.title)
            .Query(q => q.Term(f => f.title, "title", Boost: 2.0))
            );

    }
}
public class Post
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}
```

I was expecting to get the result from Post 1 because it has "title" keyword in it, but I get empty result set. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Already answered in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887276/elasticsearch-nest-client-not-returning-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the `term` query being used. This will only match **the exact text indexed**. The `term` query is [useful for id type searching](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/term-query/).

If you are doing free text searching try using the `match` query for a good general purpose free text search. [You can read more about it here on the official docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query/) and hopefully start discovering how to build interesting and powerful queries by becoming familiar with the docs.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It takes a very little time for the indexation of your Post. If you insert a Thread.Sleep(1000); between your indexation and your query, you'll have results.

Comment: While this is a good spot (and I certainly was confused by this at one point) I think it might be the type of query he is using.

Comment: If you need to get results immediately after an `Index()` use `Get()` which is realtime or if you need to get it back from the `Search()` call Index() passing `new IndexParameters { Refresh = true }` but in the long run you gain more from designing the app to deal with the Near Real Time nature of elasticsearch. Never ever rely on a Thread.Sleep for a plethora of reasons.