# Elastic-search not returning documents using Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I pretty new to `ElasticSearch`.

I'm unable to search using `ElasticSearch` i tried couple of ways, Nothing seems to be working for me.

> If i use sense chrome toolkit [Sense extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en) and query this `GET /employee/_search?q=FirstName="Eldho"` It is working Fine.

*I have already looked out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887276/elasticsearch-nest-client-not-returning-results), doesn't work for me either.*

**Unable to search using Nest**

```
    protected ElasticClient Client;
    IndexName index = "employee";

    public ElasticSearchRepository(Uri elasticServerUri)
    {
        var connection = new ConnectionSettings(elasticServerUri).DefaultIndex("employee");
        this.Client = new ElasticClient(connection);

    }

    //This is how i create Index
    public void CreateIndex()
    {

        var settings = new IndexSettings();
        settings.NumberOfReplicas = 1;
        settings.NumberOfShards = 1;

        var indexstate = new IndexState();
        indexstate.Settings = settings;


        Client.CreateIndex(index, g => g.Index(index)
              .InitializeUsing(indexstate)
              .Mappings(j => j.Map<Employee>(h => h.AutoMap(1))));

    }

    public List<Employee> Search(string search)
    {
        //All 3 searches are not wokring for me
        var response = Client.Search<Employee>(s => s
                             .AllIndices()
                             .AllTypes()
                             .From(0)
                             .Size(10)
                             .Query(q =>q
                             .Term(t => t.FirstName, "Eldho")));

        var result = Client.Search<Employee>(h => h
                            .Query(q => q
                                .Match(m => m.Field("FirstName").Query(search))));

        var result2 = Client.Search<Employee>(h => h
                     .Type("employee")
                     .Query(k => k
                     .Term(g => g.FirstName, "Eldho")));

        return result.Documents.ToList();
    }
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: If you search for `eldho` does it work?

Comment: No, In all 3 searches `documents` is 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see anywhere in your code where you're indexing any documents, but I'm guessing that you have already indexed them.

The first search

```
    var response = Client.Search<Employee>(s => s
                         .AllIndices()
                         .AllTypes()
                         .From(0)
                         .Size(10)
                         .Query(q =>q
                         .Term(t => t.FirstName, "Eldho")));
```

won't match because you are using a `term` query with `"Eldho"`, but the mapping for the field that will be performed using `.AutoMap()` will by default use a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) on the `string` field which will, amongst other things, lowercase tokens. If you were to change to a `term` query using `"eldho"`, I would expect to find a match.

Your second search

```
   var result = Client.Search<Employee>(h => h
                        .Query(q => q
                            .Match(m => m.Field("FirstName").Query(search))));
```

Will not match because by default, NEST camelcases property names when indexing, mapping, search, etc. So a property named `FirstName` on your POCO will map to a field named `firstName` in the mappings for that document type.

Your third search

```
    var result2 = Client.Search<Employee>(h => h
                 .Type("employee")
                 .Query(k => k
                 .Term(g => g.FirstName, "Eldho")));
```

suffers from the same issue as your first search.

To perform a query string query in NEST that would match the query you send in Sense

```
client.Search<Employee>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .QueryString(qs => qs
            .Fields(f => f.Field(ff => ff.FirstName))
            .Query("Eldho")
        )
    )
);
```

if you have indexed the document with NEST using the connection settings in your question, then this should work although I notice in your Sense query that you get results using the field `"FirstName"`. To change the [field inference in NEST](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#camel-casing) so that it does not camel case field/property names, we can use

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(elasticServerUri)
    .DefaultFieldNameInferrer(p => p);

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Comment: This won't  `Client.CreateIndex(index, g => g.Index(index)` any documents. ? How do i createIndex ? Is indexing document means inserting data in the search db?

Sorry i'm new to this

Comment: index and indexing are overloaded terms in Elasticsearch :) that _creates_ the index with the name in the `index` variable (you don't need the `g => g... ` part as that's specifying the index name again). Then you need to _index_ (i.e. persist) documents into the index using `client.Index(document)`

Comment: how would i search without case sensitive

Comment: That's a very _broad_ question! There are an almost infinite number of ways in which you could search without case sensitivity. The first thing that I would recommend understanding is analysis (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) and the different ways that you can index a `string` field (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/string.html). Now the simple answer to your question running with default configuration would be to execute a query that undergoes analysis _at query time_. For a single word, a `match` query will do